# main thread pfquerytableviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parse-platform, swift3

I have a pfquery tableview controller that has many pfobjects inside the class that are loading in my pfquerytableviewcontroller. I have to problems. When I refresh my table view I get this error in my debugger "Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread. 
 Break on warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug.". And when I try to swipe in my tableview, the tableview lags and slides very slowly. I assume that this is happening because the data is being loaded on the main thread. Here is my code. Can someone show me what I could do to fix both of these problems. Much appreciated. Thanks

```
class ProductTableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController{
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery<PFObject> {
    var query : PFQuery<PFObject>!


        query = PFQuery(className: "Products")
        query.includeKey("User")
        query.limit = 25
        query.skip = 25

                query.order(byAscending: "createdAt")

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "ProductTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! ProductTableViewCell

    if let files : [PFFile] = object?["Images"] as? [PFFile] {
        cell.ProductImage.file = files.first
        cell.ProductImage.loadInBackground()
    }

   }
  }
```

Comment: I used to dabble in Android. Mobile OS framework hates it when devs put important tasks in the UI thread. In Android, we implement AsynchTask to do work on another thread. Keeps you from hanging up the UI. I don't know what the bastardized Swift version of this is though.

Comment: I'm lost on what I should do. I don't think parse would create the frameworks for a pfquerytableviewcontroller with a certainty that there's always going to be an operation and crash on the main thread. There's a solution I just don't know it yet.

Comment: Try looking at http://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/
I just did and they have a query-in-background functionality mentioned for PFQuery in this guide.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a normal tableViewController?

```
var show = 0
let maxload = 250
var objects = [PFObject]()

func loaddata() {
    self.objects.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
    self.show = 25

    let query = PFQuery(className:"Ledger")
    query.limit = self.maxload
    query.findObjectsInBackground {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let objects = objects as [PFObject]! {
                for object in objects {
                    self.objects.append(object)
                }
                //reload TableView
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                print("retrieved \(self.objects.count)")

            }
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func refreshButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    loaddata()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if self.objects.count <= 0 {
        return 0
    } else {
        if show > self.objects.count {
            return self.objects.count
        } else if show > maxload {
            return maxload
        } else {
            return show
        }
    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section == self.show - 1 {
        self.show += 25
        print("showing more data")
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewController

    if self.objects.count - 1 > (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section {
        let objects = self.objects[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).section] 
    }

    return cell
}
```